# How to get data representation as string in R, like in REPL?

Tags: r, eval

I want to write interpreter for my shiny application, where I send text to R via socket and eval it in R. I want to have the same output as in R console or RStudio.

So my question is how can I convert data to string that will be the same as in Console.

I've tried:

```
toString(eval(parse(text = "10+10")))
```

but this gives:

```
[1] "20"
```

I want something like this:

```
[1] "[1] \"20\""
```

in console and when I send to browser I want the same string as in real R console.

So basically I want to write my own REPL in R.

I've also tried this:

```
r.eval <- function(code) {
  ret <- eval(parse(text = code))
  filename <- tempfile("eval_", fileext=".Rdmped")
  dump("ret", file = filename)
  str <- readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size)
  unlink(filename)
  str
}
```

but it give this:

```
> r.eval("10+10")
[1] "ret <-\r\n20\r\n"
```

Comment: Look at `deparse` or `substitute` or `rlang` alternatives? Try this: `deparse("10+10")` and maybe eval it?

Comment: `capture.output(toString(eval(parse(text = "10+10"))))`? I'm probably not understanding all your requirements. I don't even get what exactly you are trying to achieve and why it requires writing your "own REPL in R".

Comment: @Roland I want REPL in shiny in browser, to inspect R process for shiny app. You'r solution is exactly what I need , you can add it as answer.